# AS3 Air for iOS Native Dialog

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, github, air, ane

I'm trying to show date picker using this ane

https://github.com/mateuszmackowiak/NativeDialogs

Everything works fine, but for ios7 the dialog goes totally black. I tried the things like THEMES in the NativeDatePickerDialog.as but not resloved.

(OR ant other way(ane) to implement date picker). Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ANE-Alert](https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Alert) and [Date Picker](https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-DatePicker)

For the Alert:

```
 // Defining your callbacks
 var myCallback1:Function = function():void { trace("Callback 1"); };
 var myCallback2:Function = function():void { trace("Callback 2"); };

 // Display a one-button alert popup
 AirAlert.getInstance().showAlert("My title", "My message", "OK", myCallback1);

 // Display a two-button alert popup
 AirAlert.getInstance().showAlert("My title", "My message", "YES", myCallback1, "NO", myCallback2);
```

For the Date Picker:

```
 // Required params
 var currentDate:Date = new Date();
 var callback:Function = function(selectedDate:String):void 
 {
      var date:Date = new Date();
      date.setTime(Date.parse(selectedDate));
      trace("selected date = ", date);
 }

 // Native extension call
 AirDatePicker.instance.displayDatePicker(currentDate, callback);
```

Comment: how to convert this selectedDate param to Date type.

Comment: yes date picker works but in ios 7 it is totaly black and in ios8 it is not working.